# AC analysis of a oscillator

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, amplifier, oscillation

This question relates to [my previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/361535/analysis-of-an-armstrong-oscillator-circuit/361557?noredirect=1#comment894488_361557).

**I am interested in deriving an analytical relationship  for the oscillation frequency of this oscillator.**

[image]

As the first step, I have initiated the frequency domain simulations and results are as follows. In order to see the effect of the oscillation frequency, I sweep the value of C2 from 0.5pF to 6pF (oscillation sustains within this range).

The AC model is: (Mosfet capacitances are extracted from the datasheet) 
[image]

The phase and magnitudes of **voltages at secondary inductor** and **Gate voltage** are as follows. I have marked resonances close to the oscillation frequency.
simulations is done for different secondary capacitor values 0.5pF,and 5PF. 
In both the cases three resonances can be seen (say f1, f2, and f3)

When C2=5pF (oscillation frequency in time domain simulation is 8.3MHz)

[image]

When C2=0.5pF (oscillation frequency in time domain simulation is 25.1MHz)

[image]

From these results, it can be seen that the resonances in AC simulation and the oscillation frequencies are significantly different, particularly for high frequencies.

My questions are:

1. Am I moving in the right directions with the simulated AC model?
2. What could be the reasons for the disparities between AC model and time domain simulations?
3. I understand that mosfet capacitances can be varying with frequency and voltages. In addition, certain capacitances may not effective throughout the oscillation period (when the switch is fully on). How can I model the mosfet capacitances in this circuit?
4. As I am biasing the transistor just enough to start the oscilation (Vt0=4.486V and V(bias)=4.26V), can we still assume mosfet provides a 180 degrees phase shift? How can I incorporate this in the AC simulation.

**An Update**

I found a similar analysis for a slightly different oscillator in "[class-e mosfet tuned power oscillator design procedure](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1440636/)". In the analysis, they have measured mosfet capasitances at the frequency of interest and phase shift introduced by the mosfet was known (phase shit was 196 degrees in their study). If I can approximate these parameters ((i.e., **Cgs, Cgd, Cds, and phase shift introduced by the MOSFET)** at each oscillation frequency, I should be able derive an analytical (rather a semi-analytical) form of solution.

Is there a simulation based method that I can approximate MOSFET capacitances and phase shift introduced by the amplifier stage?

**Update 2**

**Trying to express the loop gain expression**

First, I tried to simplify the coupled network for the fundamental frequency component as follows.
[image]

Where reflected impedance are calculated as (Mij represents the mutual inductance between ith and jth inductor)

[image]

Now my goal is to write loop gain equations to obtain the oscillation condions
But I am not sure how should I differentiate the amplifier and feedback network

Comment: It might be worth the effort to replace the MOSFET in the transient analysis with a voltage controlled current source surrounded by the appropriate values of CGS and CGD and CDS. Then see what it oscillates at.

Comment: I don't think you can replace the transistor by its linear model because the input is very large (and not considered within "small signal" domain). You should try using describing function analysis to get accurate results.

Comment: AC simulation needs an ac source, right? Where is the source?

Comment: Moreover, I think, for identification of the oscillating frequency in the frequency domain you must do an analysis of the LOOP GAIN response.

Comment: @Andy aka, It is very close to the first resonance (f1) in the ac simulation. i.e. close to 2 MHz (I change  transconductance of the  voltage controlled current source empirically to obtain an oscillation -  but it was a increasing oscillation)

Comment: You have so much data that this is hard to understand. I would strongly advise you to simplify and just show graphs of one value of capacitance the demonstrates the problem then explain (by drawing a "marker" on that same graph) of what the real oscillation frequency is.

Comment: @sarthak, Thanks, can you pls give a head start to analyse this using "describing function analysis"? I have not studied it before.

Comment: Pojj, be aware that a resonant point does not necessarily means that at this frequency an oscillation takes place. Such a point of resonance must fulfill the oscillation criterion. For this purpose, you need the loop gan analysis.

Comment: Regarding your update: In the ref. doc they speak about class-E operation of a BJT. Are you sure that the work was based on a (necessarily) LINEAR ac analysis? It is not clear to me what you really want to do. What is the expected final result?

Comment: @LvW, Thanks, The reference talks about a class E operation of a MOSFET at a particular operating frequency. I am interested in deriving an analytical relationship between oscillation frequency and circuit parameters.  I think their design procedure can help me if I have approximate values of MOSFET capacitances at different operating conditions.

Comment: ....."between oscillation frequency and circuit parameters". For my opinion, the most direct (the only ?) way is to start with the oscillation condition (unity loop gain) - and, then solve for the desired parameter.

Comment: "An analytical model for the ...frequency" ? A "model" for a frequency?? How could such a model look like? In which form? Just a formula?

Comment: @LvW, Yes, I would like to derive a formula which includes relationship between oscillation frequency and circuit parameters. How can I apply the oscillation condition (Unity Gain and/or zero phase), without knowing the values of MOSFET capacitance?

Comment: If it is your goal to express the known oscillation condition (unity loop gain) using the various parts of the circuit, you must express the feedback factor as well as  the gain block by the relevant parts. Such a task is relatively simple for an idealized opamp - however, rather involved if the active block is realized with a transistor (which, of course) needs a realistic model description

Comment: PojjPojj
21:05
Thanks Lvw, yes, I am interested in developing an equation for a known oscillation condition of this circuit. To this end, Do you suggest a different (from the one in the question) model description for the transistor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not on my computer, but here's a quick setup of what LvW suggests:

[image: test]

You can see more of this topology in LTspice's `Examples` directory (in `My Documents/LTspiceXVII/examples/Educational`, see `LoopGain.asc` and `LoopGain2.asc`, and the links in their descriptions).

Comment: Thanks, it gives exact oscillation frequency where total phase become zero. (just that the polarity of L1 is other way then phase become zero at oscillation frequency). However, How can we deduce transistor characteristics (i.e., Cgs, Cgd, Cds, and phase shift introduced by the MOSFET) at different operating conditions from this? Here, I am interested in deriving an analytical solution. (or a semi-analytical form where numerical values of mosfet parameters are defined at each parametric sweep)

Comment: @Pojj You could explode the inner workings of the MOSFET model, but I don't think it's the way, rather, you could use an `ako` model of your MOSFET and `.step` some of its parameters, something like this: `.model BSP89x ako:BSP89 Cgs={x}`. Honestly, I think you're trying to over-simplify this, but, if it works for you, ...

Comment: Thanks, I used your method to see the effect of MOSFET model parameters (Cgdmax, Cgdmin,  Cgso, and Cjo) to the oscillation frequency. And I noticed that only Cgd affect the oscillation frequency significantly.

Comment: Rather, I would start with a very simple transistor model (ideal voltage controlled current source - perhaps with a finite output resistance. This is the first step with the aim to check if the rest (feedback factor, loop gain) is correct. Such an approach makes sense because the feedback path is not a simple one.

Comment: @LvW I tried to simplify the feedback path, but not sure how the feedback factor and loop gain is defined with this representation.

Comment: Your problem: "I am not sure how should I differentiate the amplifier and feedback network". My anser: Open the loop at the gate (allow the same DC bias), inject an ac test signal into the gate and try to find out how much of this signal arrives at the other side of the opening (due to the coupling effect between L1 and l3). This gives you the loop gain.